# Form with two submission buttons

Tags: forms, 9

I try to create a form with two submit buttons and each button will use a different function: the default `submitForm` function and a custom `submitFormEndSession` function. So I have this code:

```php
class EndSessionForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * @var \Drupal
   */
  private $drupal;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->drupal = new Drupal();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId(): string {
    return 'end_session_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {

    // ... some fields

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Close the session',
      '#name' => 'btnEnd',
    ];

    $form['stop'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Stop the session',
      '#name' => 'btnStop',
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Function to call with the btnEnd button
  }

  public function submitStopForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Function to call with the btnStop button
  }
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Submit.php/class/Submit/9.2.x) of Drupal 9.2.x, the only thing I had to do is add a `#submit` parameter to the `$form['stop']` element like this:

```php
$form['stop'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Stop the session',
  '#name' => 'btnStop',
  '#submit' => [ $this, 'submitStopForm' ] // link to the second submit function
]
```

But it doesn't work.

After many tries and researches, I've found a partial solution by adding this in `buildForm`:

```php
$form['#submit'][] = [$this, 'submitStopForm'];
```

The two buttons are now linked to `submitForm` and `submitStopForm`, no matter if I put a `#submit` parameter on the buttons or not, `submitStopForm` is executed first then `submitForm`. But I'm wonder how I can link the first button to `submitForm` and the second one to `submitStopForm` properly and without enter in both functions when we click on one button.

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers! I have a comment that is not directly related to your question: Your constructor looks very strange. You don't usually need a constructor for form classes if you don't want to inject services. And I have never seen `new Drupal()` anywhere inside custom code. May I ask where you got that from and why you use that?

Comment: Hi @berlinern, this code isn't my proper code, so I can't explain the `$this->Drupal = new Drupal()` instruction. When we got this project, it was on Drupal 8 and we made several updates to the latest Drupal version, so maybe it's deprecated code. I removed it (and the constructor too) and nothing change.

Comment: No change was expected actually ;) Did you try the other notation from the documentation that you linked to? `'::methodName'` just in case.

Comment: Yes, I already tried this but it does not working too :(

Comment: Can you post your full real code for the content of your submit functions (or a minimal example that reproduces your problem)? There is something odd there. All submit functions set in `$form['#submit']` should be called, not only the first one.

Comment: That was a mistake from me: I wrote `die()` in both with a comment for testing which function I could reach. So, I reach first `submitStopForm` then `submitForm`. But what I wanted is to reach immediatly `submitStopForm` or `submitForm`, depend of the button, and putting `#submit => [$this, 'submitStopForm']` under a button parameters not works

Comment: Please update your question accordingly. That will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Yes, please add the _actual_ code being used.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to wrap the sumbit callback in another array, if you are using that callable notation. So either:

```
$form['stop'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Stop the session',
  '#name' => 'btnStop',
  '#submit' => [ [$this, 'submitStopForm'] ] // Array of callables (which are arrays)
];
```

or this

```
$form['stop'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Stop the session',
  '#name' => 'btnStop',
  '#submit' => [ 'submitStopForm' ] //Array of submit functions
]
```

You can also get the element that triggered the action from inside the submit function, but i tend to think the previous solution is better.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { 
    $submitButton = $form_state->getTriggeringElement(); 
    dump($sumbitButton); 
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AgetTriggeringElement/8.2.x

Comment: Thanks for your response. `'#submit => [ [ $this, 'submitStop' ] ]` works, but only if I put the `#submit` parameter on the first button. Write it on the second button has nos effect. And put it on the first button change the handler for both buttons.
And if I use your second solution, both buttons has the same trigger element, I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

#submit: Specifies an alternate callback for form submission when the submit button is pressed. Use '::methodName' format or an array containing the object and method name (for example, [ $this, 'methodName'] ).

```
  /**
   * @param array $form
   * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
   * @return array
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit1'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit One'),
      "#weight" => 1,
      '#submit' => array([$this, 'submitFormOne']),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array()
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit2'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit Two'),
      "#weight" => 2,
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
      '#submit' => array([$this, 'submitFormTwo']),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array()
    ];

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitFormOne(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    //TODO: write your code
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitFormTwo(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    //TODO: write your code
  }
```